# How to set the date/time in C#

Tags: c#, datetime

How do I set the date/time of the computer in C#?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can set the date using [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Today](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9z20y6ha(VS.80).aspx) and [Microsoft.VisualBasic.TimeOfDay](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8hhbhw4c(VS.80).aspx), although they're subject to security restrictions.

Yes, it's strange accessing the Microsoft,VisualBasic namespace, but there doesn't appear to be a C# equivalent.

Comment: It's just a .NET framework namespace.  C# is not going to get infected by VB-ism just by using classes from Microsoft.VisualBasic.  The J# libraries have several goodies too.

Comment: The correct names are, Microsft.VisualBasic.DateTime.Today and Microsft.VisualBasic.DateTime.TimeOfDay.
Under the hood, both of them call the SetLocalTime() API in kernel32.

Answer (score 4):

You'll have to use a P/Invoke to the Windows API.

Here's some [example code](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32.SetLocalTime) in C#

Answer (score 0):

You will need to call the [SetSystemTime](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32.SetSystemTime) Win32 API function through P/Invoke.

Answer (score 0):

[Here's](http://forums.asp.net/p/638253/639273.aspx) a bit of code to show how to use the Pinvoke.